# Create custom token Firebase Auth in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, oauth

I see some docs create custom token from the server. But I want to create a custom token with Flutter, is it possible? If so, what should I do? Thanks

[Create custom token from Server](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens)